# Weibel's book, Page 8. $\text{Tot}(C)$. What is the sum of the horizontal and vertical differentials in a bicomplex?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

> ... define the *total complexes* $\text{Tot}(C) = \text{Tot}^{\Pi}(C)$ and $\text{Tot}^{\oplus}(C)$ by $\prod_{p+q = n} C_{p,q}$, and $\bigoplus_{p + q = n}C_{p,q}$.  The formula $d = d^h + d^v$ defines maps (check this!)

$d^h, d^v$ respectively are the horizontal and vertical morphisms of the bicomplex $C$ in an abelian category.

I don't understand how you can add $d^h$ to $d^v$ since the arrows in the commuting diagram don't indicate that it's possible.

$$
\begin{matrix}
 \ & \vdots & \ & \vdots & \ & \vdots \\
\ & \downarrow  & \ & \downarrow & \ & \downarrow \\
\dots\rightarrow & C_{p+1, q+1} & \xrightarrow{d^h_{p+1, q+1}} & C_{p, q+1} & \xrightarrow{d^h_{p, q+1}} & C_{p-1, q+1} & \rightarrow \dots \\
\ & \downarrow d^v_{p+1, q+1}  & \ & \downarrow d^v_{p,q+1}& \ & \downarrow d^v_{p-1, q+1} \\
\dots\rightarrow & C_{p+1, q} & \xrightarrow{d^h_{p+1, q}} & C_{p, q} & \xrightarrow{d^h_{p, q}} & C_{p-1, q} & \rightarrow \dots \\
\ & \downarrow d^v_{p+1, q}  & \ & \downarrow d^v_{p,q}& \ & \downarrow d^v_{p-1, q} \\
\dots\rightarrow & C_{p+1, q-1} & \xrightarrow{d^h_{p+1, q-1}} & C_{p, q-1} & \xrightarrow{d^h_{p, q-1}} & C_{p-1, q-1} & \rightarrow \dots \\
\ & \downarrow d^v_{p+1, q-1}  & \ & \downarrow d^v_{p,q-1}& \ & \downarrow d^v_{p-1, q-1} \\
 \ & \vdots & \ & \vdots & \ & \vdots \\
\end{matrix} 
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? Assuming you write $p$ for the row index and $q$ for the column index, $d^h(C_{p,q}) \subseteq C_{p+1,q}$ and $d^v(C_{p,q}) \subseteq C_{p,q+1}$. Hence $d(C_{p,q}) \subseteq C_{p+1,q} \oplus C_{p,q+1} \subseteq \text{Tot}_{n+1}^{\oplus}(C)$ if $p+q = n$.

This should appear clear if you draw a plane with coordinates $p,q$ and the modules $C_{p,q}$ as points. Then taking the total complex means taking the direct product (or direct sum) of the groups along some parallel diagonal lines. In particular, $d^h$ and $d^v$ connect modules in two adjacent lines.

Comment: How is $d(C_{p,q}) \subset C_{p+1, q} \times C_{p, q+1}$ and what do you mean by connecting modules in two adjacent lines?

Comment: Remember that a finite direct sum is the same as a finite direct product, i.e. $\oplus_{i \in I} M_i \simeq \prod_{i \in I} M_i$ whenever $I$ is a finite set. As for the other part of the question... I was really just trying to describe a diagram that I don't know how to draw on a computer. Did you try to draw it?

Comment: I will draw it real quick.  I thought it should be $d(\prod_{p+q = n} x) = (d^v + d^h)(\prod_{p+q = n} x) = \prod_{p+q = n}(d^v_{p-1, q+1}(x_{p-1, q+1}) + d^h_{p+1, q-1}(x_{p+1, q-1}))$

Comment: No, it shouldn't be, because $d \colon \prod_{p+q = n} C_{p,q} \to \prod_{p+q = n+1} C_{p,q}$. A good example to keep in mind, although in cohomology, is $C^{p,q} = \Omega^{p,q}$, the space of [complex $(p,q)$-forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_differential_form) on a complex manifold: here $d = \partial + \bar{\partial}$, where $\partial$ is the holomorphic derivative and $\bar{\partial}$ is the anti-holomorphic derivative.

Comment: How do you explicitly define $d$?  What's confusing me is their notation $d = d^h + d^v$ how is $+$ defined there?  Also the direct product may not be finite.  So you can't rely on that.

Comment: The whole direct product may not be finite, but the image of each component lies in the product of two modules. Anyway, note that $\prod_{p+q=n+1} C_{p,q}$ has a natural module structure (because it is a product module!), and here $+$ is defined point-wise: $d(x) = d^h(x) + d^v(x)$ (where $+$ is the operation that makes the product an abelian group) for every $x \in \prod_{p+q = n} C_{p,q}$.

Comment: When you say that that finite direct sum is a subset of Tot do you mean isomorphic copy?

Comment: Yes: you can naturally identify $C_{p+1,q} \times C_{p,q+1}$ with the submodule of $\prod_{p+q = n+1} C_{p,q}$ formed by the elements which are non-zero at most in the components $p+1,q$ and $p,q+1$.

Comment: Thanks then, I understand it now.  $d_{p,q} = d^h_{p,q} = d^v_{p,q}$.  First map to the direct sum of the two codomains, then include into the Tot.